# could you suggest laravel 5.1 code to insert current(present) date by the user input using form disabling others?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

{!! Form::label('Date:') !!}
{!! Form::input('date','start',null,['class'=> 'form-control'])!!}

Comment: Sorry, can you please clarify what you're trying to do? It's not very clear...

Comment: i mean to say, I want the user to insert active date of present disabling past and future dates using date format

Comment: You can't for that you need to use [`datepicker js`](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or [`datetimepicker of bootstrap`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). You can't set that within normal `date` element of HTML